# Copy Into script to copy multiple tables and for everyday run

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting this on behalf of a Snowflake User, hoping for additional insight or alternative recommendations...)

---

We are trying to copy the data from azure blob to snowflake tables using COPY INTO statement.

While creating staging area it need SAS Token.

If I want to run this copy into script using same staging area, how can I automate the staging area creation with new SAS token every day.

Is there any way other than SAS token to access blob in Azure

Also help me whether we can create stored procedure to automate all this tasks like

--> Creating staging area with SAS token

--> Creating fileformat

--> Copy into statement.

Please help me

---

***Recommendation #1:***
I recommend to take a look into Tasks or review Technology partners section on Snowflake website find ETL/ELT tool that works best for your scenario. Most tools have native intergration with Azure so you don't need to manually generate token, it will be done using keys.

---

***Recommendation #2:***
I don't think your challenge here relates to the tool you are using, but rather the expiration of your SAS Token. Are you intentionally expiring your token every 24 hours? If you extend the duration of that, then you won't have to create a new stage with a new SAS Token every day.

If you are trying to rotate SAS Tokens every day, then my suggestion would be to create a script (python or something) that actually requests the new Token from Azure and then creates then recreates your stage with the new token. Stored procedures or Tasks can not retrieve the SAS Token from Azure for you, so I'm not sure how you would fully automate this process with SP or Tasks.

---

*Any other recommendations or alternative work-arounds?*

Comment: Those are pretty good recommendations, to be honest.

Comment: I agree the recommendations are pretty good - you can create a SAS key with a longer duration. you can even restrict the SAS key to certain IPs if required for greater protection. if the file format keeps changing - then I suggest using python/scripting  which can take in parameters like the SAS key and file format and run the end to end steps.